Adding capacitors to the power stage of a DC-DC convertor (SEPIC&CUK)
I'm working on the following reference design form TI:

Based on the test report it can provide 50 mA to each rail and +60 V/-60 V. In my application there will be pulse current draw from this circuit as follows, the pulses are very short, but the peak current is 8 A:

Based on my simulation if C5 and C10 is 1 µF, then the circuit will have oscillations on the output voltage:

But when I increase C5-C10 to 68 µF there is no oscillation, but the only drawback is the the settling time of the circuit increased to 150 ms:

I plan to either increase the capacitance of the C5-C10 to higher values like 68 µF or add more capacitors on the outputs in parallel with R4 and R10.

The current of the capacitors:

In the first scenario I have doubt maybe by changing these capacitors I can affect the control loop and changing parameters like phase margin or affecting the compensation network,.... considering this circuit is designed to work for 50 mA. Am I right? or there will not be any issue by increasing these capacitors? (For sure settling time will be increase, considering it takes more time to charge larger capacitors.)
How about the second scenario? to add more capacitors (68 µF) in parallel with R4 and R10? It will be considered as load? then my pulse load can draw 8 A form these two capacitors?

Which scenario is suggested?
What type of capacitors is best suited for this application? Ceramic capacitors or electrolytic capacitors?


Are you simulating closed-loop circuit (i.e. the entire circuit) or open loop?

@Rohat Kılıç it is closed-loop simulation


... to add more capacitors (68 µF) in parallel with R4 and R10? It will be considered as load?

Without L2-C5 LC post filter, the circuit is a classical SEPIC converter. And this, instead of being a load, appears in the transfer function and, apparently, slows down the overall response (Ignore the cross-regulated negative voltage section to the bottom as the feedback is taken from the positive side).

Which scenario is suggested?

I'd say "neither".
As far as I can see, the control scheme is current-mode control and the small signal model may include L1, L3, C3, C4, ESR of C4 and the compensation network i.e. R12, C12 and C13 (some of these may not appear, I'm not sure). You also have an LC post filter which appears to be slowing down the overall response, as I mentioned above.
So it's better to re-design the entire circuit to meet your dynamic response requirements. For example, your pulse load spec appears to be really tough, so you may want to first increase the switching frequency and push the crossover frequency further (as a downside, the circuit may become high-frequency noise-sensitive). The good thing is that you are able to simulate the closed-loop circuit so you can see how the system reacts to correct the output in case of a heavy pulse load. Good luck!

can you please share the procedure, that how I can totally redesign the circuit?

@Andromeda doesn't the datasheet provide some information? You also have a simulator, that must be handy.

Rohat Kılıç in fact I need to have gain and phase margin to check the cross-over frequency to see if the system is fast enough. For example one simple steps is that I redesign the output capacitors. One simple  question should I consider  C4 and C9 as output capacitor? or C5 and C10. Then if  C4 and C9 are the output capacitors, then what are the purpose of  C5 and C10 and what is their affect in the circuit?

@Andromeda Which output do you load with the pulse current? Positive or negative?

in fact both, but in m simulation i just used the positive rail.

@Andromeda doesn't matter, actually. Since the feedback is taken from the positive rail, only that rail will be regulated. The negative rail is expected to follow the positive rail anyways since they share the same pulsating input and have theoretically identical components. So, when one rail is pulse-loaded the other will be affected due to the corrective action of the controller i.e. the controller will change the pulse width therefore you'll see fluctuations on the other rail as well. This is inevitable.

@Andromeda to answer your questions, it doesn't matter which one (C4 or C5 for positive rail, C9 or C10 for negative rail) is considered as the load capacitor. Both capacitors will probably appear in the transfer function. Without the LC post filters (L2-C5 and L5-10) the circuit is still a SEPIC converter. The LC post filters bring extra filtering, but they also slow down the response, as stated in my answer. Maybe you can simply ditch them to start with, take the feedback from C4 and see if there's any improvement. You may need to modify the COMP network, though.
